# Changing the color of a 3D plot to gray scale

Tags: graphics3d, color

MY code produces a 3D plot, but I don't like the colors. How can I change the color of the surface into grays by using `ColorFunction`?

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"`; see also [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html).

Comment: In version 10 and later you can use `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` rather than `ColorFunction`. The result is darker than using `"GrayTones"`

Comment: Alright. Thank you Bob Hanlon and @corey979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple modification of your code will do what you ask for.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[z]]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Is there a way to choose the range on z where the color function is applied ?

Comment: @HeberleyTobónMaya. It is inappropriate to ask a new question in a comment to an answer to a different question. But I will give a hint. If you had googled the phase "mathematica color function scaling", you would found [this link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/113779) which will likely give the answer you are looking for.